# How to create an ObservableCollection item which has self-remover method

Tags: observablecollection

I need to remove an item from an ObservableCollection by itself.
Is it possible doing something like this?

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
         // Constructor
    }

    public string ID
    {
         get;
         set;
    }

    public void Remove()
    {
         // I need to write some code here if it is possible
    }
}

//---------- this part is in a ClickEvent i.e.

ObservableCollection<Item> Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

Item _Item = new Item() { ID = 1 }

Items.Add(_Item);

_Item.Remove()
```

**Note: I don't want to use Items.Remove(_Item) method.**

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is for each **Item** to have a reference to its owner **ObserableCollection**

Then you can do

```
void Remove()
{
   Owner.Remove(this);
}

void AddToCollection( ObserableCollection<Item> list )
{
  Owner = list;
  Owner.Add(this);
}
```

You will also have to handle cases where items are added multiple collection.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Items collection is filled by DataContract deserializer dynamically. I don't have an idea how to reference an item to its owner in this case.

Comment: You can have a [OnDeserializedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) method that sets the owner